# Trouble selecting a option in dropdown list Selenium ChromeDriver Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver

What's up guys ?

I'm newbie in Selenium for VBA and i'm having trouble to select a option in a drop down list, following the prints... https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpcbI.jpg

I got a field called "Tipo" (image 1). This field is a dropdown list, which enables me to select some options (image 2). The option i want to select (Solicitação) doesn't appear, i got to scrolldown the dropdown menu a little bit to reach it and click (image 3).

How can i select the option "Solicitação". The SendKeys method don't work, i got a error (image 4).

```
'Escolher tipo

bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='react-select-Tipo--value']").Click

bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='react-select-Tipo--value']").SendKeys ("Solicitação")

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please share the html of the dropdown list element with options.

Comment: the html of the page: https://pastebin.com/kz5mRF3m